# Is there a way to force CMD's dir command to apply wildcards on long names?

Tags: cmd, directory, wildcard

I searched a lot but did not find related question.Sorry in advance if my question is duplicate.
I have a bunch of files with names shown below:

```
                    Eighth Text Document - Copy 8.txt
                    Fifth Text Document - Copy 5.txt
                    First Text Document 1.txt
                    Fourth Text Document - Copy 4.txt
                    Ninth Text Document - Copy 9.txt
                    Second Text Document - Copy 2.txt
                    Seventh Text Document - Copy 7.txt
                    Sixth Text Document - Copy 6.txt
                    Third Text Document - Copy 3.txt
```

when I use dir command to find files with number "1" inside their name:

```
            dir *1.txt
```

it lists all files:

```
                Eighth Text Document - Copy 8.txt
                Fifth Text Document - Copy 5.txt
                First Text Document 1.txt
                Fourth Text Document - Copy 4.txt
                Ninth Text Document - Copy 9.txt
                Second Text Document - Copy 2.txt
                Seventh Text Document - Copy 7.txt
                Sixth Text Document - Copy 6.txt
                Third Text Document - Copy 3.txt
```

it seems that the wildcard is applyed on short names:

```
                EIGHTH~1.TXT
                FIFTHT~1.TXT
                FIRSTT~1.TXT
                FOURTH~1.TXT
                NINTHT~1.TXT
                SECOND~1.TXT
                SEVENT~1.TXT
                SIXTHT~1.TXT
                THIRDT~1.TXT
```

I was wondering if there is a way to apply the wild cards on files long names only???

Comment: The only way to avoid the `dir` command to search in the short names is to remove them (`fsutil`). Without removing the short names your only option is to use some workaround that fits the problem to solve.

Comment: Is it risky to remove all short names??? what are the consequences??

Comment: It depends on where you remove them and the requirements of the software you run. See [fsutil 8dot3name](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621566(v=ws.10).aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `for %a in (*1.txt) do echo %a` and it acted the same.

So I can propose you a workaround piping the output with `findstr` and matching a regular expression:

```
dir /B | findstr /R ".*1\.txt"
```

- `.*` is like `*` in regex: any char any number of times
- `\.` to tell regex engine to match an actual dot, not the regex joker dot.
- `/B` option of `dir` only prints the filenames, making the work of `findstr` easier

will return only

```
First Text Document 1.txt
```

Comment: I could propose you a python solution, or just using `ls` from MSYS, but that's not native batch/Windows.